# What counts as a Predator Encounter?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I have completed the story without finishing all of the Dark Knight systems 'Worst Nightmare' tree (basically the challenges which reward you XP and gadgets for predator encounters).

To complete the rest of them I need to find more 'predator encounters', but what actually counts as one of these encounters? Is it just determined by a rooftop full of armed guards, or are they limited to the story section of the game where you are contained to a room?

If it is restricted to the story encounters, does your progress on the Dark Knight system get taken over when you start a NG+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Predator encounters only count toward the *Worst Nightmare* Dark Knight track when they occur while following the story.** Once you finish a predator encounter during the story, you can't repeat it to pass off any *Worst Nightmare* requirements.

I know this because I went back to the top of the GCPD building *after* my first encounter and tried to earn *Finish a predator encounter without being seen* and *Use a sonic batarang to lure an enemy into a takedown* without success. My next in-story predator encounter, however, I earned the *Finish a predator encounter without being seen*. I'm on the PS3.

I suggest picking one rank (or more if you can manage) to earn for each encounter. If you make a mistake during the encounter, pause and restart. If you fail to earn all ranks during the main storyline, you'll have to try again during New Game+.

Comment: It isn't necessarily 'story' only sections. Might just be me being picky, however I thought it's worth noting that even once you've finished the campaign, any side missions which have predator sections in, you seem to be able to progress the Worst Nightmare track (e.g. Deadshot Most Wanted)

Comment: I've completed several Worst Nightmare challenges after completing the main story line. I am blocked by level 6 (exotic takedowns) since some of the rooms don't respawn bad guys (can't get an explosive wall takedown unless enemies are near collapsible walls). But I got levels 3,4, and 5 after completing the story.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/710575-batman-arkham-origins/67623106):

> predator encounters can encouter in the city, doesnt have to be a scripted event. Look for like 2-4 armed men on rooftops and do the challenges that way

So yes, a *Predator Encounter* is a rooftop *full of enemies*. It is **not** limited to the story section, you can find *Predator Encounters* pretty much everywhere.

And yes, your progress is taken over to *New Game +*.

Comment: I am unsure if this is correct or not. I spent some time attempting to complete the latest challenge last night (#7 complete a predator encounter without using any takedowns) and couldn't unlock it. I tried the GCPD rooftop, the entrance to Sionis' steelmill and the deck of the Last Resort using only stun and beat down, and smoke. I did however notice that the XP reward system was giving me predator titles for them..?

Comment: I found [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/209000/discussions/0/648811126524202130/), which suggests that there are some difficulties getting certain challenges outside of the story, so I will have another attempt and see if I can get this unlocked.

Comment: This is not true. While you can trigger predator encounters outside the storyline, nothing you do during them goes toward earning *Worse Nightmare* track ranks.